# Gtk multiple screens

Tags: python, grid, window, gtk

I have a Gtk window that I fill with different grids. I notice that my code is starting to become a huge mess!

Basically I have 1 window with buttons. On button click, I want the Gtk Window to display a different grid. But the more screens I get, the messier my code gets.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: In what way is your code messy?

Comment: Have you tried to use a ".ui" file for the GtkGrids (maybe in a GtkStack)?

Comment: My code is messy in such a way that each grid contains buttons that can be pressed. However, I want to move certain widgets on each grid to other grids that I make visible, depending on which button was clicked. This has lead to a lot of double code. Any suggestions?